# Connect Backend with tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, backend

i'm kind of new in tkinter and im working in a personal project, the thing is that I made a backend code in python using pandas and I want to connect and use it with the GUI, in the backend code im working with local and "global" variables to pass a dataframe from one function to another. My problem is that i don't know how to connect both parts.

For example in the GUI I ask for a float that in the backend should make an operation, but I don't know how to make it, in another words, im not sure if my dataframe will exist when I call another function and make what should do with the float asked.

Comment: It sounds like you should first work through a tutorial on tkinter. What you've asked is far too broad for Stackoverflow. Work through the tutorial, try to come up with an absolutely minimal example (eg: one entry widget, one button, one backend function), and then ask a question when you can't make that work.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, thanks i'll do it as soon as posible. I'm working on that. I would appreciate if you have material to see this theme.

Comment: Specifically look at entries, labels, buttons and stringvars.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.